# Prove that the sides of the orthic triangle meet the sides of the given triangle in three collinear points.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Prove that the sides of the orthic triangle($DEF$) meet the sides of the given triangle($ABC$) in three collinear points($X, Y, Z$) . 
[image]

Prove using Menelaus theorem, Stewart's theorem, ceva's theorem

I tried to find the ratios $\frac{YA}{YB}$, $\frac{XA}{XC}$ and $\frac{ZB}{ZC}$ by getting individual values of these lengths via calculating some lengths by pythagoras and some by stewarts theorem. But I ended up with some complicated equations which when I tried to solve I was getting stuck in variables.

Comment: Is this another question (like [this now-deleted one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3623242/409)) that you'll post, then work on for a while until you solve it yourself, and then want to delete? :)  You should really do the "work on for a while until you solve it yourself" part first. That way, you can note in the question what you tried and where you got stuck (which you should do anyway). Otherwise, it seems like you're just assigning us homework.

Comment: Dude I post the questions I am stuck on one day later if I can't solve them. That question which I deleted was not solvable for me yesterday and I tried it for a minute or two today and still it wasn't solvable. But today after I posted the problem I started retrying it as I was thinking I am close and I got it what did I do wrong.

Comment: That's a reasonable approach! However, posting isolated problem statements doesn't let anyone know that you're actually being reasonable. We get a *lot* of do-it-for-me homework questions around here, so you should understand why there might be cynicism ... and you should actively work to dispel it. You do that by avoiding isolated problem statements. Tell us what you know about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc.) This will also help answerers tailor their responses to best serve you without wasting time explaining things you already know. *Help us help you.*

Comment: @Blue I edited to put some details of what I did and how I got stuck.

Comment: It is a good practice to accompany geometric questions with a drawing. Try it!

Comment: Ok I will do that do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have mentioned menelaus, i would like to post the proof using cross ratios without defining cross ratios (means a little,easy exercise for you). I will avoid directed lengths.

It is well known that $  (XE,AC)=-1$ or $\frac{CE}{CX}\frac{AX}{AE}=1$ (show this!). Similiarly, $(BA,FY)=-1$ or $\frac{YA}{YB}\frac{FB}{FA}=1$ (show this!) and finally, $(CB,DZ)=-1$ or $\frac{ZB}{ZC}\frac{DC}{DB}=1$ (show this!). Now multiply all these to get the resukt immediately.

Comment: Thanks my dude. Now I think I will be able to do this.

Comment: Good luck with geometry! :)

Comment: Can you check solution that I posted? I figured it out just now.

Answer (score 1):

This is just Desargues Theorem, but i will give an elementary proof for this one using Radical Axes and stuffs. Basically if you are taking the Menelaus approach, you solve this problem when you actually prove Desargues Theorem using only Menelaus.

It is trivial to note that $AFDC$ is cyclic as $\measuredangle AFC=\measuredangle ADC=90$. Draw the circumcircle of $\Delta ABC$ and note that by [Power of A Point](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point) we havve $\text{Pow}_{\odot (AFDC)}=XF\cdot XD = XA\cdot XC$ ($AFDC$ is cyclic) $=\text{Pow}_{\odot (ABC)}$ implying that $X$ lies on the radical axis of the circles $\odot (ABC), \odot (AFDC)$. Using a similar argument, $Y,Z$ lie on the radical axis of these circles as well and we are done.

(There are solutions using poles/polars, harmonic bundles too, for solving it with desargues, one needs to only show $AD,BE,CF$ are concurrent which is trivial)

Comment: On  note, avoid pythagoras for these problems due to only presence of $90^{\circ}$ angles, it will not let you generalise the idea.

Comment: +1 but your answer is not purely from what my book wants it from so I can't accept it sorry. I haven't even started circles from my book and it suggests using just the topics you learned from that book until that question. Basically I like your proof but can't accept it.

Comment: Then maybe a coordinate bash might help you, and can you state the topics you have covered? If i can i will surely help.

Comment: Straight Lines, Concurrence of Triangles, Parallel Straight Lines, Properties of Triangles, Similarity of Triangles, Concurrence and Collinearity.  Right now I have done only these in geometry after completing the exercise of this chapter I will go to circles.

Comment: Ok, i have given one using menelaus, but some gaps need to be filled by you (which become trivial once you learn fundamentals of projective geometry)

Comment: Can you please tell me. A good source for studying projective geometry as I am thinking that I should do that after my circle geometry.

Comment: I would suggest you not to start with projective geometry immediately after circles. I had read Euclidean Geometry in Mathematical Olympiads by Evan Chen as i am still an IMOTC aspirant. I would suggest you to understand inversion before projective as a lot of concepts in projective require inversion (Inverse points induce harmonic bundles). And this book will prove more helpful if you are preparing for olympiads

Comment: My book has inversions covered in circle geometry and I am thinking of buying even chens book after coronavirus lockdown ends

Comment: Umm you dont need to buy, i have the free pdf i could perhaps send you the book if you gave me your email?

Comment: aryan.raina000@gmail.com Thank You my dude for your help.

Comment: I have sent you can check

Answer (score 1):

By Ceva's Theorem on $\triangle ABC$ with respect to $O$(Orthocentre):
$\frac{AE.CD.BF}{EC.DB.FA}=1$.....(1)

Menelaus Theorem on $ABC$,

with respect to $DEY$:$\frac{BD.CE.AY}{DC.EA.YB}=-1$.....(2)

with respect to $DFX$:$\frac{BD.CX.AF}{DC.XA.FB}=-1$.....(3)

with respect to $ZFE$:$\frac{BZ.CE.AF}{ZC.EA.FB}=-1$.....(4)

Combining (2), (3), (4) :  $\frac{AY.CX.BZ}{YB.XA.ZC}=-\bigg (\frac{AE.CD.BF}{EC.DB.FA} \bigg)^2$.....(5)

Combining (5), (1) : $\frac{AY.CX.BZ}{YB.XA.ZC}=-(1)^2=-1$

Therefore by Converse of Menelaus Theorem $X, Y, Z$ must be collinear.

Comment: Indeed it works! Nice job. But you have a typo i will edit it